# TypeScript/React - destructuring from useContext throws an error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to work with the `useContext` hook in a TypeScript/React app. So I created a context object with `createContext` and passed a `sampleObject` to the Provider's `value` prop. When I then try to destructure the properties from `useContext`, TypeScript throws an error for each property:
**Property 'name' does not exist on type 'AppContextInterface | null'.** 
**Property 'author' does not exist on type 'AppContextInterface | null'.** 
**Property 'url' does not exist on type 'AppContextInterface | null'.** 
Here's the code:

```js
interface AppContextInterface {
  name: string;
  author: string;
  url: string;
}

const AppCtx = React.createContext<AppContextInterface | null>(null);

const sampleObject: AppContextInterface = {
  name: 'Using React Context in a TypeScript App',
  author: 'thehappybug',
  url: 'http://www.example.com'
}

const App = () => (
  <AppCtx.Provider value={sampleObject}>
    <PostInfo />
  </AppCtx.Provider>
);

const PostInfo = () => {
  const appContext = useContext(AppCtx);
  // typescript throws the errors on the next line
  const { name, author, url } = appContext;
  
  return (
    <div>
      Name: {name}, Author: {author}, url: {url}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Not sure what the problem is...

Comment: i believe its because it starts as null...
you could either start with a empty object or maybe treat the `null` case

Comment: You're trying to desctructure properties from a variable that can be null. In order to make it work you'll need to check if the object actually exist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `appContext` can be null, you need to handle that case

```
const PostInfo = () => {
  const appContext = useContext(AppCtx);

  if (!appContext) return null;
  const { name, author, url } = appContext;
  
  return (
    <div>
      Name: {name}, Author: {author}, url: {url}
    </div>
  );
}
```